# localhost ip stops working on https

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

The RESTful calls to my Spring Boot project were working fine when using the default http, with using the localhost alias as well as my localhost ip address e.g. http://localhost:8080/getCall, & http://xx.xx.xx.xx:8443/getCall.

When enabling https on the project, the calls are working fine using localhost alias, but not the localhost ip address, which gives http error 0. e.g. https://localhost:8443/getCall working, https://xx.xx.xx.xx:8443/getCall not working. Strangely when calling https://xx.xx.xx.xx:8443/getCall directly through Chrome browser, it takes me to Proceed with Caution page, and once proceeded, issue goes away entirely. Although this is a hack, and still needs to be resolved.

Here is the code used to enable https..
Inside WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter subclass, and override method; configure(HttpSecurity http):

```
http.requiresChannel().antMatchers("/**").requiresSecure();
```

Inside application.properties, in src/main/resources (where also myRecepientsCert.p12 resides created with command line tools):

```
server.port=8443
security.require-ssl=true
server.ssl.key-store=classpath:myRecepientsCert.p12
server.ssl.key-store-password=not-telling
server.ssl.key-store-type=PKCS12
server.ssl.key-alias=myRecepientCert
```

Here is full code to example project I am using..

MyRestController

```
package com.learnspring.SpringBootHttps;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
@CrossOrigin("*")
public class MyRestController {

    public class POJOForJSON {
        public String key;
        public String key2;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/getCall", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
    public POJOForJSON getCall() {
        POJOForJSON json = new POJOForJSON();
        json.key = "value";
        json.key2 = "value2";
        return json;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/postCall", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "application/json")
    public POJOForJSON postCall() {
        POJOForJSON json = new POJOForJSON();
        json.key = "value";
        json.key2 = "value2";
        return json;
    }
}
```

SpringBootHttpsApplication

```
package com.learnspring.SpringBootHttps;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringBootHttpsApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringBootHttpsApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

WebSecurityConfig

```
import java.util.Arrays;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfiguration;
import org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfigurationSource;
import org.springframework.web.cors.UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource;

@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
        .cors() // allow CORS calls with @CrossOrigin annotation on restful call
        .and().csrf().disable()
        .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/**").permitAll();

        http.requiresChannel()
            .antMatchers("/**").requiresSecure();   
    }


     @Bean
    CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
//      configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("http://localhost:8100"));
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("*"));
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET","POST"));
        configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);
        configuration.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("Content-Type", "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "x-authorization-firebase"));
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;
    }

}
```

Comment: what is the domain name listed on the certificate that you are using?

Comment: Domain name not a cert attribute!? Here is the contents printed out using, keytool -list -v -keystore recepientsCert.p12:  Keystore type: JKS
Keystore provider: SUN

Your keystore contains 1 entry

Alias name: recepients
Creation date: 14-Jun-2018
Entry type: PrivateKeyEntry
Certificate chain length: 1
Certificate[1]:
Owner: CN=my name, OU=Unknown, O=Unknown, L=Toronto, ST=Ontario, C=CA
Issuer: CN=my nam, OU=Unknown, O=Unknown, L=Toronto, ST=Ontario, C=CA
Serial number: 4c99d18c
Valid from: Thu Jun 14 12:39:33 EDT 2018 until: Sun Jun 11 12:39:33 EDT 2028

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer the question, the self-signed certificate is doing what it's suppose to do. They are not automatically trusted, and are used for TEST/DEV environments. You need to have a publicly signed certificate for a PROD environment. To do that I am yet to find out (but I think you can get it from AWS, if you have an account).